# Retrieve website files from Laravel Forge/Digital ocean

Tags: laravel, github, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I have a website that was made by someone. I’m trying to get my files and want to be able to update some front end stuff. He made the website with Laravel Forge and Digital Ocean. He has his account connected to his Github I think. I was able to ssh into my Forge with keys. I also have a sudo pass and database pass if this helps. He’s MIA btw deleted all his social stuff and website and won’t respond to emails.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if you have access to the server you should have everything there including assets and any other files and the database, if you have access to the github you should have the application code itself

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to GitHub so the easier way is to download the files from the server there are many ways to do it  as example by using FileZilla then create a new repository in GitHub and push your code to the repository in GitHub  then you can deploy from GitHub to the server